# add apps to top panel in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: panel, top

Is there any way to add any app I wish to the top panel in Ubuntu 12.04? e.g, I have dropbox, mail, wireless and sound icons there. I'd like to add for example terminal, google earth or any app there.

Also, what's the shortcut for the task manager, that shows the processes and some specifications of the computer?

Answer (score 12):

If you are using GNOME panel then you can add any application in there. All you have to do is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Click</kbd> in panel. Click **Add to panel** and then select **Application Launcher** and click forward.

[image]

Then choose your desired application from list and click **add**.

[image]

You are done.

Comment: I have the Unity Desktop with Ubuntu 12.04 and "Add to panel" does not appear with Super+Alt+right click. I used "Add to panel" before with the classic Gnome desktop in previous versions of Ubuntu. Is this unavailable in the Unity Desktop or is there another way add apps to the top panel?

Comment: Hey @Cee! I had the same problem using 12.04's classic desktop. I found that you're able to click and drag icons there, but there is no "add to panel". What I did to fix this was to find where the bin is at (using "whereis ___"), then go there using the file system GUI, then click and drag it up there

Answer (score 1):

You might want to pose the two questions as two different ones. As for adding an app in the top panel, if you are using Gnome classic, you can simply drag the specific app from the drop down menu under "applications" onto the top panel.

To see the processes, you can choose "system monitor" from under application -> system tools.

Answer (score -1):

If you just follow these instructions:

1. open the application, the application will appear in the launcher on the left side,
2. now press <kbd>Super/Window</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>
3. then right click on the application on the launcher and click on ***lock to launcher***.

Now the application is permanently locked to launcher.

Comment: He asked if an icon could be added to the **top panel** in Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score -1):

this helped me:

1. start the application so the app icon appeared in the Launcher
2. super/win + right click on the app icon in the Launcher (no Alt pressed)
3. click "Lock to Launcher"

my system:
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Question is about the top panel, not the launcher. You cannot add anything but indicators to the top panel in unity.