# Where to locate a tgz file and contents of it?

Tags: installation, package-management, filesystem, directory

I downloaded processing-2.0.1-linux64.tgz.

In Windows, when I download a non-install software (.exe) I locate it under Program Files directory so that it stays with other software. I don't want it to run in Downloads or somewhere else. I'm vety miticulous about my directory structure.

So in Ubuntu I want processing software to run just like firefox. I mean when I write 'proc' , it should show up in gnome activities window.
I don't know where to locate a tgz file and contents of it? There is "Add downloaded package" in Synaptic file menu. I tried it however the tgz file was disabled, not clickable.

[image]

This is contents of processing-2.0.1 folder.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly a `.tgz` file is not a program file.  It is an `gz` compressed `tar` archive file, and as such is not runnable.  Usually, this will be a source package and will need to be built.

It appears you have already expanded it into a directory.  If not the command `tar xzf processing-2.0.1-linux64.tgz' will expand it.  I would copy or move it to`/opt` and expand it there

From the contents it appears to be Java based program.  And will fail if you don't have Java installed.

Open a terminal window and `cd` to directory where you have expanded the archive.  Try running `processing` and `processing-java`.  Remember which one starts the program as you want.

To run the program from the classpath (assumes expanded to `/opt/processing-2.0.1`) create the following file in a different directory. (I'll use the name `processing` ).

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
cd /opt/processing-2.0.1
./processing
```

Then run the following command to add make it executable it to `/usr/local/bin`.

```
sudo mv processing /usr/local/bin
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/processing
```

You can also edit the menu to add a new item, or create a desktop icon.   In either case you would use the full path to the program.

To understand where `linux` puts its file read the output of the command `man hier`.

Comment: I've already run the program. It works fine but it is in Downloads directory. I just asked where is the appropriate place to store it in (like firefox stored)?

Comment: The appropriate place is `/opt`.  I posted before my response was complete.  The command `sudo mv processing-2.0.1 /opt` run from the `Downloads` directory should put it in the correct place.

Comment: If you want to learn more about Linux filesystem directory structure, read the Wikipedia article on FHS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: Ok it runs in /opt now. How to use Synaptic to handle this? There is "Add downloaded package" in Synaptic file menu. I tried it but the tgz file was not clickable.

Comment: Synaptic is not the tool for running applications.  Try searching for add apps to the panel for results like this. http://askubuntu.com/questions/165562/add-apps-to-top-panel-in-ubuntu-12-04